# Consequences of not upgrading Expression Engine?

Tags: expressionengine

How necessary is an Expression Engine software update for an existing website that works fine? I have version EE 2.11.6 and have been advised to upgrade to version 4 --at great expense.

I need the site to work for maybe five more years before I retire my business. It is a simple brochure site for a photography business displaying pictures and text with a blog and a contact form. Nothing fancy, no sensitive customer data, nothing of interest to hackers.

If I don't do the upgrade, is it really likely to stop working anytime soon? Would upgrading to version 3 instead of 4 give me a few more years?

Thanks in advance!
Dennis

Answer (score 1):

whether it will keep working largely depends on your hosting environment.  If your hosting environment stays the same, you don't want new functionality (ie plugins), and you have no payment systems involved, you could probably make this site stretch another five years.  On the other hand, if your host wants to upgrade operating systems and PHP versions, eventually EE 2 will not be an option.

An upgrade to EE 3 is a big jump from EE 2.  The jump from EE 3 to 4 is not nearly as difficult.  What creates the cost in upgrading is often incompatible plugins.  The EE 3 release changed the underlying code framework to the point that many useful plugins were abandoned and many developers decided to exit the EE marketplace.   Finding replacements and re-working the functionality the plugin got you can be time consuming and expensive.

By the way, every site has something of interest to hackers.  Your content is not necessarily the end goal, if they can get access to your server through some exploit, they can then use it to send spam emails, host a botnet, or use the computing power for their own purpose with obscured traceability.  That can bring negative consequences for your site in the form of blacklisting and other penalties for being hacked.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed to hear! Sorry I don't have the reputation to upvote.

Comment: You might be able to accept the answer, even if you can't upvote - but anyway, glad you got what you needed.